# What is the difference between "People who live ..." or "People living ..."

Tags: difference

Are there any differences between the following sentences?

- **People who live** on their own are often feeling lonely.
- **People living** on their own are often feeling lonely.

Other examples:

- **Those who go** to the gym many times a week feel invigorated at work.
- **Those going** to the gym many times a week feel invigorated at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1]  *People* [*who live in on their own*] *are often feeling lonely*.
>
> [2] *People* [*living on their own*] *are often feeling lonely*.

Syntactically, both bracketed clauses modify "people". The difference is that in [1] it's a relative clause, in [2] a gerund-participial clause.

Semantically, they are very similar and there's little to choose between them, though statistics show that [2] is more common than [1].

The same applies syntactically to your other two examples, though semantically it's the relative clause that is the more common.

Comment: Don't know why someone down-voted your explanation. Thanks anyway! I think you explained it clearly. Basically, they're both okay but one is more common than the other, right?

Comment: @pilti Yes: that's correct.